# Angular 2 System src can't find core stuff (without packages)

Tags: angular, config, systemjs

Have one interesting issue with System.js and Angular 2.

In default quickstart we have this system config:

```
System.config({
      packages: {
        built: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });
    System.import('built/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

It's works for me.
But now I try to move all files from built upp. So main.js file on one level with index.html. So for now  system package can't be deployed.  Because thy need some folder name (all node_modules installed correctly on the root folder with all angular2 stuffs).

And I try to use some simple config:

```
System.config({
       defaultJSExtensions: true
    });
    System.import('main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

but got many errors like this:

> system.src.js:1061 GET
>   http://localhost:3000/angular2/platform/browser.js 404 
>   system.src.js:1061 GET http://localhost:3000/angular2/router.js 404
>   (Not Found)

http://prntscr.com/ardlin

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think it is because system don't know where she must looking (node_module). But it is just idea..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you forgot to include the Angular2 bundled files:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script -->
```

Because SystemJS can find modules they contain, it tries to load from .js since you set the `defaultJSExtensions` attribute is set to `true` in its configuration.

Comment: Hi Thierry, glad to see you :)
no, unfortunatelly, in my index.html all bundles are included
http://prntscr.com/ardx9n

Comment: when I remove defaultJsExtensions  from System config. - got error: angular2-polyfills.js:332 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)

I renamed main    to main.js  because I removed default extension, but it`s failed.

Dont know what use this System and Angular2 withoud packages setting. My main file  on the same level with index.html

Comment: Hey! Me too ;-) I think that there is a problem with your imports. It seems that there are 404 when trying to load corresponding files. Could you check this?

Comment: actually you are right, but I don't understand why. I got 304 from index file and 404 from System. js

http://prntscr.com/are2qz
my import:    http://prntscr.com/are3wn  and ts file: http://prntscr.com/are450

Comment: the response is ok: http://prntscr.com/are69t   I think issue with system configuration

Answer (score 0):

Thierry) you helped me a lot again. Thanks friend :)

Founded one of your oldest answers for simillar issue
[Angular2 systemjs issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156966/angular2-systemjs-issues)

You are right. We *MUST* keep all angular js files in some folder. This folder must be placed at the same level with index.html and register it like local package.  It's really strange and interesting rule, but whatever.